# PHP doesn't execute functions with sql correct

Tags: php, sql, database, function

I will put my code below. I basically check on value in the database and if it's 1 or 0 i want to change it to the opposite (so if 1 change it to 0, if 0 change to 1).
If I execute one SQL statement without using the function (but then it only works one way once) it works. But if I want to execute the specific function with it depending on what the value currently is, it doesn't seem to work. Do you know what I am doing wrong here?

```
<?php 
$date_id = $_POST['dateID'];
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","secret_name");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM date_list WHERE date_id = ".$dateID;
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $occupied = $row['occupied'];
    if($occupied == 1){
        decross_entry();
    } elseif( $occupied == 0){
        cross_entry();
    }else{
        echo "Error"
    }
}

function decross_entry(){
    $dateID = $_POST['dateID'];
    $con_2 = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","secret_name");
    $sql_edit = "UPDATE date_list SET occupied= '0' WHERE date_id = ".$dateID;
    if($con_2 -> connect_errno){
        echo "Failed to connect to database!" . $con_2->connect_error;
    }
    if ($con_2 -> query($sql_edit) === TRUE)
    {
        echo "saved!";
    } else {
        echo "error: " .$sql_edit."<br>".$con_2->error;
    }
}

function cross_entry(){
    $dateID = $_POST['dateID'];
    $con_2 = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","secret_name");
    $sql_edit = "UPDATE date_list SET occupied= '1' WHERE date_id = ".$dateID;
    if($con_2 -> connect_errno){
        echo "Failed to connect to database!" . $con_2->connect_error;
    }
    if ($con_2 -> query($sql_edit) === TRUE)
    {
        echo "saved!";
    } else {
        echo "error: " .$sql_edit."<br>".$con_2->error;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: When the select query is called second time, what is the value in $row['occupied']

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_error.asp

Comment: @AA On default occupied is always zero. Only when the function "cross_entry" is called, it changes to 1. Is this what you wanted to know?

Comment: So is it calling cross_entry at first and updating to 1?

Comment: @roubs3019 . . . Learn to use parameters!

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. You should use prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

If the only possible values of `occupied` are `0` and `1` then you can do what you want in one query without needing to look up the value of `occupied` first:

```
UPDATE date_list
SET occupied = 1 - occupied 
WHERE date_id = ?
```

In PHP, using a prepared query to avoid [SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1):

```
$date_id = $_POST['dateID'];
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","secret_name");
$sql = "UPDATE date_list SET occupied = 1 - occupied WHERE date_id = ?";
$stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('i', $date_id); // use 's' if $date_id is not an integer
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: You can add `and occupied in (0, 1)` to more accurate reflect the OP's code.